# ValueError: X has 19 features, but LinearRegression is expecting 20 features as input

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, machine-learning, regression

I'm trying to do polynomial regression using this code here:

```
x_train,x_test,y_train,y_test = train_test_split(self.X, self.y, test_size=split, random_state=random)
        for i in range(1, len(self.dataframe.index)):
            self.polyModel = PolynomialFeatures(degree=i)
            self.X_poly = self.polyModel.fit_transform(x_train)
            self.polyModel.fit(self.X_poly, y_train)
            self.model.fit(self.X_poly, y_train)
            y_poly_pred = self.model.predict(x_test)
            if (r2_score(y_test, y_poly_pred) > self.highest):
                self.poly_degree = i
                self.highest = r2_score(self.y, y_poly_pred)
        self.polyModel = PolynomialFeatures(degree=self.poly_degree)
        self.X_poly = self.polyModel.fit_transform(x_train)
        self.polyModel.fit(self.X_poly, y_train)
        self.model.fit(self.X_poly, y_train)
        self.score = self.highest
```

but I'm getting this error:

```
ValueError: X has 19 features, but LinearRegression is expecting 20 features as input.
```

does anyone know how I might fix this problem?

Thanks!!

Comment: Try printing x_train.shape and x_test.shape. I guess you are trying to train with 20 features and testing with 19 features. Please give more detail on the error, like which line exactly throws the error.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: the error is on the line ```y_poly_pred = self.model.predict(x_test)``` Running the ```.shape``` function shows that I indeed have 19 features